# Getting all records as NULL while reading a Simple JSON file in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Scala and I am learning Spark with scala.
Problem -> 
I am having Simple JSON file having 20 fields and 100 records.
I have created a code which reads the JSON file and save it as csv. So everytime I am reading the JSON file I am getting the null values in the dataframe.

CODE ->

```
sql_c = SQLContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
df = sql_c.read.format("json").load("data.json")
df.show()
```

I am getting all the records as NULL.
Please help me out and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the spark session.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.json("data.json")
df.show()
```